# JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have below code

```
const pageArea = (Component:ReactNode,title:string) => ({ ...props }) => {

    return (
      <>
       
          <div>
           
            { Component && ( <Component {...props} /> )}
             
          </div>
      </>
    );
  };
```

Its throwing error

> JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call
> signatures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because ReactNode is a node you can not call it in the way you call Component.

I guess you mean Component is a React Component. So, to fix it, please change the type from `ReactNode` to `React.ComponentType` OR `React.ComponentClass` OR `React.FC` (what ever you want).

> JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures reactjs

Comment: Thanks, that worked,could you help me understanding the syntax of const pageArea = (Component:ReactNode,title:string) => ({ ...props }) => {},  component and title are params of this function then what is ...props, or you can give me some link of similar kind of syntax to understand

Comment: There are some keywords that would help you: React high order component (HOC), React Function Component, React Props type. Some links for you: https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-higher-order-component-patterns-in-typescript-42278f7590fb, https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/effective-use-of-typescript-with-react-3a1389b6072a/

Comment: Thanks for those links, but still unable to find that syntax, like If I say that is a kind of arrow function then normal syntax is like const pageArea = (Component:ReactNode,title:string) => {} ,, but how additional ({ ...props }) => works

Comment: You need to understand about the high order component concept. From the second arrow function is a generated component that created by high order component.